# Is Wasco Sans font available as a web font?

Tags: web-fonts, font-licensing

Is Wasco Sans font by Jim Wasco available as a web font?

Comment: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/font-identification-requests-teach-a-man-to-fish

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is substituting for a simple Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wasco Sans is a [custom font that was designed for Microsoft](http://www.adobe.com/products/type/font-designers/jim-wasco.html). While it seems to be freely available for use for games developed in [XNA Game Studio](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/utility/font_pack), I can't seem to find it anywhere else on Ascender's site. Since they made the font and sell web fonts on their site, I'd say it's safe to assume that Wasco Sans is not available for web font usage.

Of course, you're welcome to [contact Monotype](http://www.ascendercorp.com/contact/?Ref=gamefonts) if you want a more definitive answer. Feel free to post the results of your inquiry as an answer here!

Comment: Thank you, very complete answer. I sent a mail. We'll see.